# How to change recognized file type in PhpStorm 10?

Tags: phpstorm, phalcon, volt

I did mistake for recognizing ***.volt** file type as **XML**. It's supposed to **Twig** file types. I've read on many sources just like opening menu on "Settings->Editor->File Types". I can't find any "File Types" menu in this version nor the plus button to add another file types. What must I do then? I know this is a silly question, but still make me frustated. Thanks

Comment: Hard solution: navigate to .Webide100/config directory and find file with content volt. Probably it will be XML file. Then you can remove extention and restart phpstorm. I will try to repeate your case and find how to revert it in phpstorm.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. @funivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft solution:
Open `Settings->Editor->File Types` go to `XML` and find `*.volt` there. Then just remove it.
[image]

Hard solution: navigate to `.Webide100/config` directory and find file with content `volt`. Probably it will be XML file. Then you can remove extention and restart phpstorm.